# How to use Simple hierarchical select on a view starting at second level taxonomy?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I am using the [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) on a view for a an exposed taxonomy term, but I want the first level of the taxonomy to be preselected, so that the user can only choose the second and third levels.
I tried to do this by adding jquery to change the first element, but it doesn't load the second level taxonomy then.

Is there a parameter in this module so I can preselect the first level taxonomy term and not let the user change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a patch to allow you to choose the parent taxonomy at a level lower than the root. I will post a link to it soon .   If anyone wants to ask me about it in the meantime please write to me.

Comment: Hey Diana, FYI: this answer showed up in the review queue "as low-quality because of its **length** and **content**". Can you think of improving/extending your answer? eg by adding more details about that patch, or maybe a link to the patch?

Comment: Hi Pierre, yes I will but give me a day to clean it up. thanks